# trouble with cookies

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a folder test in my localhost.
In file test/cookie/a.php:

```
 <?php setcookie('email','abc@gmail.com',time()+3600);?>
```

In file test/cookie/b.php

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE['email'] ?>
```

A file name test/x.php, I write code

```
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['email'];
?>
```

first, I run file a.php, after that I run b.php, and x.php. But only file a.php display abc@gmail.com, file x.php show error:

Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\x.php on line 2.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User the form optional `path` paramter for set cookie `'/'` to set the cookie for whole domain.

```
<?php setcookie('email','abc@gmail.com',time()+3600,"/");?>
```

Now you will have email in other files too. Check [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)